# What does LMO mean?

Tags: mars, low-earth-orbit, mercury

I know that LEO means low Earth orbit. I thought that LMO would mean low Mars orbit, but my friend said it means low Mercury orbit. Does LMO mean low Mars orbit, low Mercury orbit, none of those or both of those?

Comment: I have also seen LMO used for "Low Moon Orbit" but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit  the correct name should be "Low Lunar Orbit".

Comment: Presumably it could mean any of those  dependent on the context

Comment: In space.SE, its usage has been sticked  for Mars, e.g. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37850/is-a-mars-return-mission-by-starship-possible-without-local-propellant-productio but as user438383, it can be used for either planet depending on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Chrome extension [NASA Acronyms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nasa-acronyms/anpbkdhjbebjjkgdbglbcfaenjldbinf) (and [accompanying website](https://nasaacronyms.com/)) suggest these three options for LMO:

[image: LMO meanings]

- Low Mars Orbit
- Low Moon Orbiter
- Lunar Magma Ocean

According to the [master json list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nasa/NASA-Acronyms/master/lists/acronyms.json) these particular acronym meanings are sourced from NASA Langley.

Answer (score 4):

There are usages of M for Mars in some other abbreviations, such as MER for Mars Exploration Rover. A couple entries use M for Mercury, but these appear to relate to the space program as opposed to the planet.

One celestial object M is generally not used for is the Moon; usually L for Lunar is used instead. The Moon, as "Lunar", is the only object besides Earth for which abbreviations are listed for orbits, as with LOI (Lunar Orbit Insertion) and LLO (Low Lunar Orbit).